# How to create procedure for script logging in Firebird 2.5?

Tags: logging, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to call logger procedure ('p_ADD_TO_LOG') from another procedure to understand how script executes.

My logger looks like:

```
create PROCEDURE p_ADD_TO_LOG (
 IN_MESSAGE Varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EMPTY'
)

AS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO tmp_logging (ID, mess)
 VALUES (gen_id(id_gen, 1), :IN_MESSAGE) ;
suspend;
END
```

The problem is that if in the executed procedure where the `p_ADD_TO_LOG` is called, an error occurs or executed procedure will not be commit than the `IN_MESSAGE` will not written to `tmp_logging` table.

It seems it is because that these procedures are executed in the same transaction.

How to change 'p_ADD_TO_LOG' so that it wrote to the log if the transaction is not confirmed or if an error occurred in the called procedure?

Comment: It seems `IN AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION DO ` will help me.

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem using `IN AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION`, consider posting your own answer with details of your solution. It might help other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `IN AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION DO` in pocedure

```
create PROCEDURE p_ADD_TO_LOG (
 IN_MESSAGE Varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EMPTY'
)
AS
BEGIN
IN AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION DO
 INSERT INTO tmp_logging (ID, mess)
 VALUES (gen_id(id_gen, 1), :IN_MESSAGE) ;
suspend;
END
```

and it works.